# Multiple instances of Node Webkit (nwjs) shares cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, node-webkit

I have two nwjs apps running in different nwjs executables. But cookies for both app are stored in the **same** folder `C:\Users\Nickname\AppData\Local\node-webkit`. For example, I can access cookies of the second app from the first (!!!). It's confusing.

So, one app can stole cookies from another app just using code `win.cookies.get()`? How to store cookies for each app separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your app and change the `data-path`, if you don't want to access the running arguments, you can use child_process, for that, the main app will create new app that store the cookies in diferent folder.

```
var child_process = require('child_process')
var path = require('path');
var profilePath = path.join(gui.App.dataPath,Math.random());
var child = child_process.spawn(process.execPath, ["--data-path="+profilePath,"],{detached: true});
```

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3724

I recommend you to not use cookies for save app data. You can use files (fs module).
You can also try to encrypt your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to upvote, but I can't :( It says I need 15+ rep to upvote.